# Google Data Studio Date Range Filter -Report Level

Tags: google-data-studio

I am creating multiple reports in Google Data Studio, I want to persist my date range selection for all reports. I have made date range control as 'Report Level' If I am creating multiple pages on same reports then It is working fine but it is not working for different reports ?

Is it possible to achieve this functionality for different reports ?

Answer (score 1):

You partly answer your question. The feature is for "Report Level" in the same report. At the moment, you can have multiple pages follow the report level rule in the same report, but there is no feature to accommodate different reports.

Comment: Thanx for the clarification